# OS X Keyboard Alt key language

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard, mojave

I use a MacBook with English keyboard and sometimes I need to write something in my mother language, which is Turkish. So I can write the characters with <kbd>Alt</kbd> key. But I changed the computer at office and now I can't write characters that I want. I want to write <kbd>ı</kbd> but it writes <kbd>ˆ</kbd> .

Is there any way to set up the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key language?

The older computer had an English keyboard but now I have dutch keyboard on the computer. I set the keyboard with U.S..

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Looking into System Preferences → Keyboard → Input Sources. Add the keyboard of the desired language and see if "Use the Caps key to switch to and from <language>" works for you.

Comment: Thanks for reply but it didnt work :(

Comment: What is the mother language you are writing with the alt key?

Comment: Turkish. I needed to turkish character.

Comment: You can't write Turkish with the US layout.  Change to Turkish qwerty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to system preferences/keyboard/input sources and make sure that only Turkish Qwerty or Turkish Q - Legacy is on the list and everything else is gone.